# How to test expected delay time on page element (fixed wait, debounce) with Playwright

Tags: playwright, debouncing

How to test implemented fixed delay on webpage with Playwright (exactly: debounce)?

I have simple scenario. User, after entering input need to wait fixed time for response i.e. 1000ms.
How to test that exact wait with Plawright?

Looked at https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4405 but I wonder if there is more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well usually there is a better way than to hardcode a waiting time.

- Wait for certain API calls
- Wait for network idle (= wait for started calls to finish)
- Wait for an event

However there are times when hardcoding is inevitable. What I've used is page.waitForTimeout()

Wait for 2 seconds:

```
await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
```

Official docs: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-timeout

> "Waits for the given timeout in milliseconds.
>
> Note that page.waitForTimeout() should only be used for debugging.
> Tests using the timer in production are going to be flaky. Use signals
> such as network events, selectors becoming visible and others
> instead."